# Magento 2, Soap as service reference, access to different Shops

Tags: magento2, soap

I need to access to two different shops in one Magento 2 instance.

Haven't found out yet, how to tell the interface (using Visual Studio and Service References) which of the shops / frontends I want to access.

Is there an easy example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No idea about service references in Visual Studio, but I assume that with "different shops in one instance" you mean different stores. Then the solution is that Magento offers a different API endpoint for each store.

Citing http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/soap/bk-soap.html:

> ### Soap WSDL Endpoint Format
>
> ```
> http://<magento_host>/soap/<store_code>?wsdl&services=<serviceName1,serviceName2,..>
> ```
>
> The value of store_code can be one of the following:
>
> - `default`
> - The assigned store code
> - `all`. This value only applies to the CMS and Product modules. If this value is specified, the API call affects all the merchant's
>     stores. `get` operations cannot be performed when you specify `all`.

Comment: You're right I meant different stores. What I'm looking for is an example, how I can modify the endpoint URL so that it is possible to fetch data from all the stores in one program. In Magento 1 / Soap V2 there was a login function with parameters for different URLs, which don't seem to be present in Magento 2.